# Is it possible to seamlessly connect to a MySQL database hosted on 000webhost.com from a JavaSE application?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I uploaded a MySQL database on the above mentioned site containing some user account information for a small project I'm undertaking. The goal is to allow each client application to connect to the database and retrieve information relevant to the user. Is it possible to do this with this or any other free database hosting website and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not do this.

MySQL connections are not encrypted by default; anyone who can sniff your client's network traffic can read everything that goes across the wire (including usernames and passwords for your database). If you are storing personal data (which your question suggests), that data is vulnerable.

Sniffing network traffic is one of the easiest attacks - anyone on a public WiFi network is vulnerable.

I do not know if 000webhost.com allows you to connect to the MySQL database from "outside" - you should contact their support team. I'm guessing not, though.

Finally - please read the FAQ on here - asking for tools or services is off topic.

Comment: Noted and thanks for the heads-up. Though I thought using SSL would solve the problem

Comment: You have to set up encryption explicitly - and it's not trivial.

Comment: The common way of exposing data like this is to wrap the database in an API, rather than pushing SQL across the internet. SOAP and REST can be encrypted and secured.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to connect to any mySQL database until and unless the site you mentioned as provided you with the following :

```
1) JDBC Driver 
2) Password and Username  
3) URL to DB
```

Read the instructions and build your application as needed : [http://www.000webhost.com/forum/][1]

And as Neville K pointed out, such hosting is quite vulnerable and your application might be susceptible to sniffing.